# Filter MYSQL addresses

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with addresses. The street name **does not include** the type of road (e.g. "Street" or "Avenue").

The query to filter the results is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}coverage
WHERE Street LIKE '%$_GET[Street]%'
AND NUMBER LIKE '$_GET[NUMBER]'
AND Province LIKE '$_GET[Province]'
AND TYPE != 'null'
```

Now, if I enter "Holland" in the search form, it filters the results correctly, the same as if I enter "land".

The issue is that if a user tries to filter, for example, by "Holland Street", no results are returned because the word "Street" does not exist in the column.

How can I make it filter it, skipping words that are not in the registry?

Comment: *`AND TYPE != 'null'`* `null` is a non value while `'null'` is a string

Comment: You should use `TYPE IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for that information, but it doesn't solve the question.

Comment: *How can I make it filter it, skipping words that are not in the registry?* The simplest way is to cut off "Street"/"Avenue" from entered value (REPLACE function). More complex way - parse entered value to separate words then check against each separate word. There are more ways to solve, I think.